# Container of objects indexed by definite field

Tags: java, java-8, containers

I have a set of objects I need to index by definite field of objects. There is a sample implementation with HashMap (***UPDATE:***  Actually, HashMap is used just for illustration, I do not insist the container I looking for surely be a HashMap)

```
public class Foo {
    public String id; // The Field to index by

    // some other fields just for number
    public int i;
    public double d;
    public String description;
    public String rule;
    public double otherD;

    public Foo(String id, int i, double d, String description, String rule, double otherD) {
        this.id = id;
        this.i = i;
        this.d = d;
        this.description = description;
        this.rule = rule;
        this.otherD = otherD;
    }
}
```

I need to have a container of `Foo` objects indexed by unique string field `id`. So the following `fooHashMap` is a current solution:

```
HashMap<String, Foo> fooHashMap = null;

fooHashMap.put("bar", Foo("bar", 1, 0.3, "aa", "bb", 0.8));
fooHashMap.put("tzar", Foo("tzar", 8, 12.3, "dlj", "no rule", 0.343));
// etc.
```

It looks pretty ugly solution to doubling `id` in `Foo` constructor and in hashmap key. Can java 8 suggest more elegant solution?
I do not mean solution like

```
public void addFoo(Foo foo) { fooHashMap.put(foo.id, foo); }
```

Comment: `public Multiplier` is what?

Comment: Why don't you want the `addFoo` solution?

Comment: Thank you @nullpointer. Typo is fixed

Comment: @ModusTollens Actually, I would prefer do not have two copies of same data if it possible, because of necessety track the consistence of both copies. For example, there is Boost.MultiIndex in c++ world. I hope there is some alike solution in java (maybe with streams)

Comment: @Loom How would using the `addFoo` solution create two copies of the same data? Java 8 streams could only make this slightly more elegant, but only if you already have a list of `foo` objects.

Comment: @ModusTollens I need to implement not only `addFoo`. Also I need to remove, edit objects in container etc. And in these cases I need to track the consistence. Maybe it isn't too complicate to implement. However, I would prefer some native solution, if exist any

Comment: @Loom Maybe I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you have a data model of Foo objects? Maybe then you are looking for a lookup function and not for a map. Or do you really create Foo objects several times "on the fly"? Can you please edit your question with more information?

Comment: @ModusTollens There is a description of my current task https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173457/hashmap-of-objects

Comment: @Loom In that question you ask if the Divider code is common practice. If that is the question, I would answer "yes". But to avoid putting the same String twice as Id and as part of the constructor use one of the methods in the answers below.

Comment: @ModusTollens The Codereview question is a more common question. With stackoverflow I would like to try just my hope for existence of specific container type in java and around

Comment: @Loom Sorry, I am out of ideas. The answer to your question as it is now is below, if you are looking for something else than a HashMap, then please ask a new question. I am still not sure what you need.

Comment: @ModusTollens I've updated question. Maybe it looks more clear now, what I am looking for. In c++ Boost.Multiindex you can have collection indexed by some field (or even have some different indexes by different fields). I hoped java has some analogue. Not necessarily java itself. Maybe some library, like guava implemented alike functional.

Comment: @Loom done, added

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use the solution you have posted at the end:

```
addFoo(new Foo("bar", 1, 0.3, "aa", "bb", 0.8));
addFoo(new Foo("tzar", 8, 12.3, "dlj", "no rule", 0.343));
```

and let the `addFoo` method handle the rest:

```
public void addFoo(Foo foo) {
    fooHashMap.put(foo.id, foo);
}
```

Since you apparently have to create the `Foo` objects anyway I can't think of a more elegant solution.

If you already had a list of `foo` objects, you could create the map like this

```
Map<String, Foo> fooMap = foos
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.id, f -> f));
```

Answer (score 2):

The following using java-8 might help you:

1. Implement getter(`getId()`) for the unique key `id`.
2. Iterate through a list of `Foo` named `fooList` and collect it as a Map as follows:

   ```
   HashMap<String, Foo> = fooList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getId, o -> o))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing; but depending on what exactly you might need, creating such methods - lets say groupBy certain fields would not be hard at all.

Removing and editing would again not be that hard to implement via some TreeMap lets say... But there is no such thing out of the box. The only thing Ive found is [this multi index container](http://github.com/Kamosh/multiindexcontainer)